# ASP.Net Warnings and Errors after following a tutorial - Need assistance

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, error-handling, warnings

I'm in a web programming class and our current assignment has to be done using ASP.Net. The problem and cause of my frustration is due to my professors lack teaching, unclear directions, and outdated "guide." I'm using the 2012 version of Visual Studio Ultimate.

I'm supposed to make a completely different program than this "guide," but I have no idea how I'm supposed to do so when I have all of these errors/warning doing EXACTLY as his guide shows.

In his poorly written guide.. he states: "Upon debugging a few errors will show up. Fix them and your webpage will display."  Yet using his code and following everything as he did.. I have 52 errors and 3 warnings. I searched for most of them on Google and only found Q&A specific questions for other peoples programs.

There's not much code and I don't get how there are so many errors from replicating my professors code/guide. I'll add some of the errors/warning followed by the code from the files below. If someone can help me fix some of these errors, I'd more than greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

### 3 warnings:

```
Warning 34  Function without an 'As' clause; return type of Object assumed.     \\vmware-host\shared folders\Documents\Visual Studio     2012\WebSites\CS316Program5\game.aspx.vb   26  14  CS316Program5(1)
Warning 50  Function without an 'As' clause; return type of Object assumed. \\vmware-host\shared folders\Documents\Visual Studio     2012\WebSites\CS316Program5\game.aspx.vb   58  14  CS316Program5(1)
Warning 53  Function without an 'As' clause; return type of Object assumed. \\vmware-host\shared folders\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\CS316Program5\game.aspx.vb   91  14  CS316Program5(1)
```

---

### Some of the 52 errors :(

```
Error   1   'Context' is not a member of 'game'.    C:\Users\Justin   Geis\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET   Files\root\95a42970\24c7c528\App_Web_mrk1wbiu.0.vb    128 

Error   3   Class 'game_aspx' must implement 'ReadOnly Property IsReusable As     Boolean' for interface 'System.Web.IHttpHandler'. Implementing property must have matching     'ReadOnly' or 'WriteOnly' specifiers.  C:\Users\Justin Geis\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary     ASP.NET Files\root\95a42970\24c7c528\App_Web_mrk1wbiu.0.vb    144 

Error   4   Class 'game_aspx' must implement 'Sub ProcessRequest(context As HttpContext)' for interface 'System.Web.IHttpHandler'.  C:\Users\Justin Geis\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\95a42970\24c7c528\App_Web_mrk1wbiu.0.vb    144 

Error   5   'GetWrappedFileDependencies' is not a member of 'ASP.game_aspx'.    C:\Users\Justin Geis\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\95a42970\24c7c528\App_Web_mrk1wbiu.0.vb    163 

Error   6   'Server' is not a member of 'ASP.game_aspx'.    C:\Users\Justin Geis\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\95a42970\24c7c528\App_Web_mrk1wbiu.0.vb    166 

Error   7   property 'SupportAutoEvents' cannot be declared 'Overrides' because it does not override a property in a base class.    C:\Users\Justin Geis\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\95a42970\24c7c528\App_Web_mrk1wbiu.0.vb    169 

Error   8   Value of type 'ASP.game_aspx' cannot be converted to 'System.Web.UI.Page'.  C:\Users\Justin Geis\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\95a42970\24c7c528\App_Web_mrk1wbiu.0.vb    230
```

### game.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="game.aspx.vb" Inherits="game" Debug="true" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Customer Data</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    Name:
    <asp:TextBox ID="username" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="username" ErrorMessage="name required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" onClick="nameEntered" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <h1>
        <asp:Label ID="pageloaded" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </h1>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" Visible="false">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <br />
            Zip Code:
            <asp:TextBox ID="Zip" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="ZipChanged"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Label ForeColor="Red" ID="errormessage" runat="server" Text=" ">        </asp:Label>
            <br />
            Address:
            <asp:TextBox ID="Address" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Label ForeColor="Red" ID="errormessage2" runat="server" Text=" ">    </asp:Label>
            <br />
            City:
            <asp:TextBox ID="City" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            State:
            <asp:TextBox ID="State" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Label ID="updatemessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### game.aspx.vb

```vb
' game.aspx.vb
' asp.net vb.net example
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Security
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts
Imports System.Web.UI.HtmlControls
' code behind is in a class like this
' the name customer must match the name in the inherits
' attribute of the page directive at the top of the aspx file
Partial Class customer
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
' zipchanged executed when user clicks in address textbox
Function ZipChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    ' verify that user entered 5 digits for zip code 
    ' using regualr expression pattern matching
    Dim myMatch As Match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(Zip.Text, "^\d{5}$")
    ' if 5 digits entered
    If myMatch.Success Then
        errormessage.Text = "" ' blank out any previous error message
        updatemessage.Text = "City/State updated at " + DateTime.Now.ToString()
        ' VB case (select/switch) statement
        Select Case Zip.Text  ' select on zip code entered
            Case "40502"
                ' update text boxes
                City.Text = "Lexington"
                State.Text = "KY"
            Case "60609"
                City.Text = "Chicago"
                State.Text = "IL"
            Case Else  ' entered zip code not found
                City.Text = ""
                State.Text = ""
                updatemessage.Text = "Unknown zip code"
        End Select
    Else  ' invalid zip code entered
        errormessage.Text = "zip code must be 5 digits"
        City.Text = ""
        State.Text = ""
        updatemessage.Text = ""


    End If
End Function
' Page_Load executed whenever page is loaded by user
Function Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ' Page.IsPostBack is used to check if this is
    ' the first load of the page (not an Ajax update)
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        ' first load - not Ajax update of page
        Dim I As Integer  ' iterator for cookie search
        Dim foundcookie As Boolean = False ' flag if cookie found
        Dim currenttime As String ' current time kept here
        currenttime = DateTime.Now.ToString()
        ' Running on your local PC cookies kept
        ' under "localhost". Iterate thru all local cookies. 
        For I = 0 To Request.Cookies.Count - 1
            ' If not first execution within 24 hours
            ' the time was put in a cookie named LastAccess
            If Request.Cookies.Item(I).Name = "LastAccess" Then
                foundcookie = True
                ' Get the cookie value and display to user
                pageloaded.Text = "Page last loaded at: " +  Request.Cookies.Item(I).Value
            End If
        Next
        If Not foundcookie Then
            pageloaded.Text = "First load of page at: " + currenttime
        End If
        ' Save current time in a cookie named LastAccess
        Dim myCookie As New HttpCookie("LastAccess")
        ' cookie value
        myCookie.Value = currenttime
        ' cookie expires in 24 hours
        myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(24)
        ' now add the cookie (name in myCookie: LastAccess)
        Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie)
    End If ' if not first load of page
End Function
Function nameEntered(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Button1.Text = "Clicked"
    UpdatePanel1.Visible = True
End Function
End Class
```

---

### Web.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some code missing here, among other things.

The code-behind class - game.aspx.vb - is referenced in the page declaration at the top of game.aspx: -

```
CodeFile="game.aspx.vb" Inherits="game"
```

But the class in game.aspx.vb is called `customer` ? This won't work. The 'inherits' part of the page declaration clearly states it is looking for a class called 'game'.

Also, a bunch of your errors are related to an IHttpHandler implementation: -

```
Error   3   Class 'game_aspx' must implement 'ReadOnly Property IsReusable As     Boolean' for interface 'System.Web.IHttpHandler'... (snip)
```

Apparently, these are in a class called `game_aspx` which is not in anything you posted.

Your lecturer is trying to get you to solve stupid and confusing problems before you have seen how things work properly. This is an idiotic way of teaching, especially when he is showing you a whole load of concepts you probably haven't seen before.

I feel sorry for you. Nobody should have to suffer such poor quality teaching.

Anyway - if you can dig out the rest of the code and post it, I might be able to help.

Comment: I completely agree. This professor is terrible. This guide I'm following - you'd think an uneducated 8 year old came up with it. He's inconsistent with casing and referring to his code. It's a confusing mess of chaos! His "teaching" of ASP.Net was a link to W3Schools! However this is the code he provided. We have to use this garbage to simulate a card matching gambling game. He was too lazy to rewrite the guide and it's dated 2010. This program used to be a customer lookup simulation. I changed the name to game (I caught that eventually lol). I don't know why its doing game_aspx though

Comment: Oh well, once you've graduated you'll be able to appreciate the confusing mess of chaos that is most real-world projects.. *sigh* Good luck :)